# IIS7 URL ReWrite Module: Force to root

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

We have two sites in IIS7 both on port 80. One is our actual website (MAIN) the other is a maintenance site (MAINTENANCE) that we start (and stop the other one) when we are deploying a new version of MAIN.

When we put MAINTENANCE live, if you browse to one of our subfolders (i.e. http://maintenance/product1) you'll get a 404. I want to use the URL Rewrite module to redirect to the root of the site (http://maintenance/).

I can get this working in a basic manner, but the image and css are not working. In other attempts I have ended up with a continual redirect.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who arrives here via Google, I managed to get it to work with the following rule:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Force HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Allow Local Resources" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="SiteMaintenance.png" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="Stylesheet.css" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Check Is Root" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^.+$" negate="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
        </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

No idea if this is the best way, but it worked for me.

:)